# Creating a separate boost thread for endpoint.listen() in a multithreaded program using websocketpp library

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, websocket, boost-thread

I am trying to integrate a websocketpp server into a multithreaded project. Everything works fine in a single thread approach, but I encountered a problem when creating a separate boost::thread for endpoint.listen() that would run in the background (so it does not disrupt the execution of the main thread). I have tried the code with Boost v1.46.1 and v1.50.0 on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit with the newest build of websocketpp. Below is a code sample and an explanation of my approach.

```c++
#include <websocketpp/websocketpp.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <exception>

using websocketpp::server;

class echo_server_handler : public server::handler {
public:
    void on_message(connection_ptr con, message_ptr msg) {
        con->send(msg->get_payload(),msg->get_opcode());
    std::cout << "Got message: " << msg->get_payload() << std::endl;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    unsigned short port = 9002;

    try {       
        server::handler::ptr h(new echo_server_handler());
        server echo_endpoint(h);

        echo_endpoint.alog().unset_level(websocketpp::log::alevel::ALL);
        echo_endpoint.elog().unset_level(websocketpp::log::elevel::ALL);

        echo_endpoint.alog().set_level(websocketpp::log::alevel::CONNECT);
        echo_endpoint.alog().set_level(websocketpp::log::alevel::DISCONNECT);

        echo_endpoint.elog().set_level(websocketpp::log::elevel::RERROR);
        echo_endpoint.elog().set_level(websocketpp::log::elevel::FATAL);

        std::cout << "Starting WebSocket echo server on port " << port << std::endl;

        //Getting pointer to the right function
         void(websocketpp::role::server<websocketpp::server>::*f)(uint16_t,size_t) =
                &websocketpp::role::server<websocketpp::server>::listen;

        std::cout << "Starting WSServer thread... \n" << std:endl;
        boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> ptr(new boost::thread(boost::bind(f, &echo_endpoint, port, 1)));
    //ptr->join();

    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    //Simulating processing in the main thread
    while(true) {std::cout << "Main thread processing..."<<std::endl; sleep(5);}


    return 0;

}
```

If I compile the code with *ptr->join();* the listening thread works fine, but it makes the main thread sleep. If I leave *ptr->join()* out and let the listening thread run in background, I encounter an error after the thread creation:

> /usr/local/boost_1_50_0/libbin/include/boost/thread/pthread/recursive_mutex.hpp:105:
>   void boost::recursive_mutex::lock(): Assertion
>   `!pthread_mutex_lock(&m)' failed.

I'm not very experienced with threading or boost threads, and quite new with websocketpp, so I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong here. If there are any better (and working) ways to tackle this issue, I would love to see some examples. I have been trying to figure out this problem for a long time now, so any help would be priceless. Thanks in advance!

Check out also: [gdb stacktrace](http://pastebin.com/Jcd6MGSy) and [valgrind results](http://pastebin.com/Cf2nmf4t)

**Edit:**
The "while(true)" in the code sample is there just to simulate the processing in the main thread. I'm integrating a websocket server in a big project that has different types of socket connections, events, data processing, client synchronization etc. running in the background. The websocket connection provides just another way to connect to the server using a web client instead a native one. The main thread creates all the necessary stuff, but I can't really affect in which order they are created, so the websocket server must be started in its own thread.

Comment: You can find the websocketpp samples [here](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/blob/master/examples/) or in the sample folder of your websocketpp copy.

Comment: I have tried out all the examples. My code sample is a modified version of the echo_server example.

Comment: There is another example - a [concurrent server](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/tree/master/examples/concurrent_server). It demonstrates how to create a multi-threaded server.

Comment: Without `ptr->join` the server and its handler are destroyed after leaving the `try-catch` scope. That is why there is the assertion.

Comment: If I understood correctly, in the concurrent server example, a separate thread is started for processing each request. However, the socket listener that waits and processes connections still stops the main thread and thus prevents any concurrent processing in the main thread.

Comment: I think the best way is to create a new thread, do what you need there and set the main thread to wait for all threads in the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you creating the `boost::thread` on the heap, when it could be on the stack?

You don't need to use `boost::bind` with `boost::thread`, so it should be simply:

```
    boost::thread t(f, &echo_endpoint, port, 1);
```

Much simpler, no?

As for your program's behaviour. If you call `ptr->join()` there then the main thread waits for the other thread to finish, which never happens, so of course it sleeps.  If you don't join it then `ptr` and `echo_endpoint` and `h` all go out of scope. The other thread will then be trying to use objects which no longer exist.

As @IgorR. [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11507071/981959), you should put the `while` loop inside the try-catch block, so the work in the main loop can happen *before* the other thread and the objects it uses go out of scope.

From Boost 1.50 the `boost::thread` destructor matches the behaviour of `std::thread` i.e. it calls `terminate()` if the thread is joinable when its destructor runs. This is to prevent the sort of error you have, where the thread continues running even though the `boost::thread` handle referring to it and other stack objects no longer exist.  If you want it to keep running you must `detach` it explicitly (but in your program that would still be wrong, because the `echo_endpoint` and `h` objects would still cease to exist and the thread would still try to use them.) So before a `boost::thread` object goes out of scope you should either `join` it or `detach` it.

Answer (score 1):

You create all the objects within the scope of try/catch. When you leave this scope, these objects get destroyed.

So, either move the object definitions out of try/catch, or move `while(true)` loop into it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll look more more on that tomorrow and report if  I got it working or have more problems.